# Problemas con C# y TextMode ="Number"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas noches, actualmente tengo un gran problema con c# en asp.net, sucede lo siguiente: A los textbox les ando colocando un textmode="Number" para que solo agregar números, resulta que por una extraña razón Visual Studio 2012 me manda este error :

> Error 6   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' no contiene una
>   definición para 'Number'  C:\Users\Alejandro
>   Fernandez\Desktop\MarketVenezuela\market_RegistroEmpleado.aspx    77

Lo que tengo entendido es que no está en su librería, pero si me da la opción de ponerlo no debería aceptarlo?.
Gracias por su ayuda muchachos

Comment: que framework estás utilizando? (en properties del proyecto)

Answer (score 3):

Asegurate que estes usando Framework 4.5 en adelante, de 4.0 hacia abajo no permite ese tipo de dato aunque por la versión de Visual Studio probablemente por eso el intellisense te lo sugiera.

[Fuente](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/new-html-5-input-types-in-asp-net-4-5)

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente este tipo de error da porque no es una función soportada.
Verifica que tu proyecto lo hayas realizada con el Framework más actualizado, de no ser así, actualiza e intenta nuevamente.